# android thread still running after pressing back button

Tags: android, multithreading

I want to stop a thread when a back button is pressed.
I'm using `Handler`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Handler`'s `removeCallbacks()` function.

Sample code:

```
@Override
public boolean onBackPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(yourRunnable);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: @siten: How are you able to determine if your thread is still running?

Comment: @siten: Please post some text about it. What do you mean by *shows me the value of thread?*.

Comment: @Viktor is there any solution that after back button my thread will close.. i m never break my thread during current execution

Comment: @siten: That text is not telling me much. What do you mean by *shows me the value of thread*?

Comment: i continue generating thread and each time thread return me that value... but after back button it shows continuously show after 5 sec that i used in postdelayed. thae value is..  HDFC.BO;buy;620;620;655;640.1;false_

Comment: @Viktor onbackpress method is work... this problem is solve thread is stop. but what removerallbacks do exactly??

Comment: @siten: Yepp, since you putting the `Runnable` into the `postDelayed` function if you want to execute it again.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use either `stop` or `destroy` methods.
In the `onStop` method you have to use [this](http://www.forward.com.au/javaProgramming/HowToStopAThread.html).

Comment: He is using `Handler` which isn't in the same context like an originally `Thread`.

Comment: ya u r rite. we cant stop or destroy thread and method.. thanks for show me guide kine.. one up vote for you.. thank you so much...

Answer (score 1):

Store a reference to the thread when you create it. In your activity's `onPause`, pause or kill the reference thread.

Comment: @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
  handler.removeCallbacks(r1);
  super.onBackPressed();
 } that is ok??

Comment: That's not correct. Use the `removeCallback()` function from `Handler`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an action on back button press by overriding the `onBackPressed()` function in your activity. This action must have a command to stop the thread.  It will appear as below.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
             thread.stop();
}
```

Comment: i used handler...and thread.stop();or handler.stop(); not posible in backpress

Comment: did you give the thread a name and used it in onBackPressed ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo to stop the thread an easier and faster way.

```
Button back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back);
back.setText("Back");
back.setOnClickListener(this);

private Handler handler = new Handler() 
{
@Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
    {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        if(msg.obj.toString().contentEquals("hello"))
        {
            // do whatever u what to perform after thread stop....
        }
        removeDialog(0);
        }
 };

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    if(v==back)
    {   
        showDialog(0);
        t=new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                Message toMain = handler.obtainMessage();
                toMain.obj = "hello";
                handler.sendMessage(toMain); 
            }
        };          
        t.start();
    }
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
{
             switch (id) 
        {
                    case 0: 
            {
                          ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                          dialog.setMessage("Connecting . . . . . .");
                          dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                          dialog.setCancelable(true);
                          return dialog;
                    } 
              }
              return null;
}
```

Use this method to create or stop the thread. I hope that it would take less time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using handler you can just remove the callbacks by  handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
This Should perfectly work. Happy Coding :)